# How to draw line betwen two points in VtkChart?

Tags: c++, vtk

After draw a scatter plot with vtk, i would like to draw separate lines into scatter plot.
Could you help me please ?

I tried this :

```
        vtkLineSource *line = vtkLineSource::New();
        line->SetPoint1(0, 0, 0);
        line->SetPoint2(1, 1,1);

        vtkPolyDataMapper *map = vtkPolyDataMapper::New();
        map->SetInput(line->GetOutput());
```

But i don't work because i use VtkChart to draw my scatter plot as in this example http://www.itk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Plotting/ScatterPlot

Comment: Want some coffee, while we're at it?

Comment: I can't help you, I've never worked with Vtk; but perhaps somebody else who has worked with Vtk, and who might have helped you had you put any effort into this, won't help you because... now... where did I put it? http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/